# How do I keep the player 1's X stay after its player 2's turn in a tic tac toe game in php?

Tags: php, html

I have to make a tic tac toe game in php, this is what i have done so far:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<?php
//vars
if (!ISSET ($_POST['submit'])){
 $_POST ['value'] = '';
}
//players
if (!ISSET($_POST ['turn'])){
 $turn=1;
  $ul='';
  $um='';
  $ur='';
  $ml='';
  $mm='';
  $mr='';
  $ll='';
  $lm='';
  $lr='';
}
else{
 $turn=$_POST['turn'];
 if ($turn==1){
  $turn=2;
  }
  else{
  $turn=1;
  }
}  
//boxes

$ul='ul';
$um='um';
$ur='ur';
$ml='ml';
$mm='mm';
$mr='mr';
$ll='ll';
$lm='lm';
$lr='lr';
//forms
$box= $_POST ['box'];

//Calculations
//player 1
if ($turn==2){
if ($box == $ul){
 $ul = "X";
}
if ($box == $um){
 $um = "X";
}
if ($box == $ur){
 $ur = "X";
}
if ($box == $ml){
 $ml = "X";
}
if ($box == $mm){
 $mm = "X";
}
if ($box == $mr){
 $mr = "X";
}
if ($box == $ll){
 $ll = "X";
}
if ($box == $lm){
 $lm = "X";
}
if ($box == $lr){
 $lr = "X";
}
}
//player 2

else{
if ($box == $ul){
 $ul = "O";
}

if ($box == $um){
 $um = "O";
}
if ($box == $ur){
 $ur = "O";
}
if ($box == $ml){
 $ml = "O";
}
if ($box == $mm){
 $mm = "O";
}
if ($box == $mr){
 $mr = "O";
}
if ($box == $ll){
 $ll = "O";
}
if ($box == $lm){
 $lm = "O";
}
if ($box == $lr){
 $lr = "O";
}
}
?> 
<table width='100pX' height='100pX' border='1'>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $ul;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $um;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $ur;?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $ml;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $mm;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $mr;?></td>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $ll;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $lm;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $lr;?></td>
 </tr>

</table>
<?php echo 'Player ' . $turn .  ", it's your turn"?>
<form method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'>
<input type='text' name='box'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $turn;?>" name='turn'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $ul;?>" name='ul'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $um;?>" name='um'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $ur;?>" name='ur'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $ml;?>" name='ml'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $mm;?>" name='mm'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $mr;?>" name='mr'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $ll;?>" name='ll'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $lm;?>" name='lm'>
<input type='hidden' value= "<?php echo $lr;?>" name='lr'>
<input type= 'submit' name= 'submit' value= 'Go'>
</form>

</html>
</body>
```

When i enter player 1's answer in the form, the desired box turns X, but then when its player 2's turn the x goes away and player 2's O shows up. How do I fix this??

Comment: What happens to the data in your hidden inputs when you hit submit?

Comment: i think they stay the same or they all turn x''s or o's

Comment: They vanish because you're not doing anything with POST['ul'], for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value to the next form.  You're doing a hidden input for each of the pieces in your form, but you're not getting the values.

Right below the $ul = 'ul', you need to put

```
$ul = $_POST['ul'];
```

etc for all the values.  This will let you pull the previously set values into the current form.

Comment: so do i get rid of these:

Comment: $ul='ul';
$um='um';
$ur='ur';
$ml='ml';
$mm='mm';
$mr='mr';
$ll='ll';
$lm='lm';
$lr='lr';

Comment: now i'm getting all O's in my grid

Comment: I'm not sure what that part does, but on future moves you need to pull your past board state into the current page with $_POST, and pull your hidden values.

Comment: I edited the code above.  Basically right below every $ul = 'ul'; you need to put a $ul = $_POST['ul'];